# Is it possible to SEO a full-WEBGL / Three.js website so it won't be at a disadvantage?

Tags: seo, single-page-application

I would like to know if there are any tricks of the trade to make a **full-WEBGL website**, search-engine optimized, so it won't lack behind conventional websites due to the kind of technology it uses alone (unfair treatment from search-engines).

Also, I'm talking about a **single-page website**, as I want to minimize waiting for the user and give a sense of uninterrupted user experience via predicted loading on the background when necessary.

So, are there any valuable tips, sources, whatever for **single-page WEBGL SEO**?
There doesn't seem to be any books on the subject!

Comment: Isn't WEBGL for 3D rendering in a web browser?   If you have just one page on a site that only consists of a 3D rendering, what you are hoping to rank for?   Search engines are getting better, but they still need text with keywords on the page.   Multiple pages also help because home pages typically rank best for brand names.   People searching for solutions tend to land on deeper pages.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller Granted, the output can be purely visual and thus inaccessible, but the labels and hyperlinks shown can be created from readable JS data if necessary. Its most part (except the shaders) is still based on simple javascript that downloads, processes data and accepts user input like in any other JS application. 
Even Flash that used Actionscript could be crawled, and information could be extracted by google to some degree years ago, wouldn't JS be easier nowadays?

I bet there are a few who have learned valuable tips via trial and error and can answer this question.